# Cocoa Touch - Changing tex attributes?

Tags: cocoa-touch

How can I change a textview font and font size..

I've tried this but it doesnt seem to change anything...

`typingText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt Thin" size:64.0f];`

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this is Mac. I need to update my favorite tags to cocoa-touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual name of the font is "MarkerFelt-Thin".

```
typingText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MarkerFelt-Thin" size:64.0f];
```